# MySQL Statement HAVING COUNT(*) < t.row - Including Nulls

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently trying to get the following statement to work:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.row2
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.rowx = t2.rowx
JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.rowy = t3.rowy
GROUP BY t1.row2
HAVING COUNT(t2.rowx) < t3.maximum_size
```

The statement works and provides an output, however a lot of the `t3.maximum_size` fields are `NULL` which then prevent the statement working as desired.

Is there a way to have a `COUNT(*)` < `another_number` including `NULL` values?

Example:

```
10 < 20 // true
20 < 20 // false
18 < null // true (as null represents no maximum size in my query)
```

(I did check other SO questions which there are lots relating to the issue, but I haven't seen one helping with this specific task - if I have missed one please point me in the right direction.)

Comment: Is this statement even legal? `t3.maximum_size` is neither a `group by` field nor an aggregate function, so this should trigger an error.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: This is MySQL. Your ANSI SQL logic has no place here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the having clause to:

```
Having count(t2.rowx) < t3.maximum_size or t3.maximum_size is null
```

In retrospect, a better SQL answer is:

```
Having count(t2.rowx) < max(t3.maximum_size) or max(t3.maximum_size) is null
```

The original syntax works in mysql but not in most databases.  Also, I consider it to be bad SQL.  The use of "t3.maximum_size" is really equivalent to "any value for t3.Maximum_Size" when referred to in an aggregation context. It is much better to be explicit.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to aggregate `t3.maximum_size` as well:

```
HAVING COUNT(t2.rowx) < MAX(t3.maximum_size)
```

Comment: No - the HAVING clause is identical to the WHERE clause, just that you can use aggregates in it.  The HAVING clause does not require everything within it to use aggregates.

Comment: @OMGPonies Does it ever make sense to use a `having` with a `group by` on any column that is neither a `group by` column nor a parameter of an aggregate function?

Comment: MySQL supports using the HAVING clause to reference a column alias without using a derived table/inline view.  HAVING doesn't require a GROUP BY either...

Answer (score 1):

May be you can use NVL

```
HAVING COUNT(t2.rowx) < NVL(t3.maximum_size, 0)
```

This will mean in case the t3.maximum_size is returned as NUll then the matching will be done with ZERO

Hope it helps